# gtkmm application with Gio file monitors

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gio

I need to monitor multiple directories for changes. I'm using `Gtk::Main`, calling `Gio::Init`, and adding directory monitors exactly as the documentation suggests. However, the callback is never called, for any directory. Do I need another loop solely for the monitors, and if so, how would I use it in conjunction with `Gtk::Main`?

Comment: Are you following any example code?  See here: http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/gtkmm-documentation/trunk/examples/book/giomm/monitor_directory/monitor_directory.cc?revision=83&view=markup

Comment: Yes, I'm following that example. The thing is, how do I use `Gtk::Main` and `Glib::MainLoop` at the same time? Apparently using Gio's FileMonitor's requires `Glib::MainLoop`. I even tried a separate thread, but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in Vala and here is the complete solution.

As pointed out by Andrea Azzarone, you can use the `Gtk::Main` loop.

However, pay attention to your `Gio::FileMonitor` reference. At the end of the function, it is destroyed so that the callback won't be called if you don't keep a reference to the `Gio::FileMonitor` object.

I found this idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727937/callbacks-and-gtk-main-loop#answer-12336038).

Answer (score 1):

You can use just Gtk::Main loop because it is a Glib::MainLoop.